# Debian don't login as user after partition resize

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, xfce

I have a workstation with a Debian  8 with a XFCE and 8GB hdd. I want to resize a partition. I do:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sda1
resize2fs -M /dev/sda1 #resize fs to minimal size;
fdisk /dev/sda1 #remove partition; write;
fdisk /dev/sda1 #create partition with smaller size; write;
resize2fs /dev/sda1 #resize fs to maximal size;
```

After this I have broken system. I get a logout if I login as user. There is no error if I login as root. Where I can look for an error in system logs?

Comment: `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/auth.log` are possible candidates. You could also check if the `/home` partition exists and if it's mounted, error-free, etc., that would explain why you can login as `root` (which is on a different partition) but can't do with a regular user.

Comment: The operation you have performed deletes the partition content, so whatever you had on `/dev/sda1` is now gone. Did you back it up before the resize? If not, then  you can only reinstall it. What is the mount-point of the partition?

Comment: I have only one partition. After resize i have >100 mb space.

Comment: Can you provide the info `mount`, `cat /etc/passwd` ?

Comment: Did you do this on a live filesystem? You should first have reduced the filesystem size, only then reduce the partition size. If there was data beyond the new end, the resize operation can't reach it to copy it to a safe location.

Comment: I do this from live puppy.